# web folder permission issue with Wordpress using Nginx in CenterOS

Tags: centos, nginx, wordpress

OS: CentOS release 6.2

In nginx.conf, I set web user as nginx as the following,

```
user nginx nginx;
```

The mod of plugin/uploads folders is like the following

```
drwxr-xr-x. 11 nginx nginx 4096 23:09 plugins
drwxr-xr-x.  4 nginx nginx 4096 11:13 uploads
```

As you see, the plugins/uploads folders are owned by nginx, and "rwx" by nginx, but why when I try to update plugins via wordpress dashboard, I still get permission denied.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Where are those directories?  And is SELinux set to enforce?

Comment: Is your php part running as php-fpm or somehow else? If it ir running as php-fpm you need to check as what user it is running and chown your wordpress root directory to this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's php-fpm settings which override the user/group settings in nginx.conf, and I just need to set to "nginx" and fixed the problem.

http://www.caiapps.com/web-user-and-group-setting-in-nginxphp-fpm-env/